# onClickListener inside recyclerView and replace a fragment accordingly

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

`onClickListener` inside `RecyclerView` and replace a fragment accordingly. 
cant get `fragmentManager` inside static method, or am I doing it wrong.
I am listening for a click in the adapter then calling a function in the `recyclerview` then trying to replace the `fragment`, but can't `getAvtivity()` there.

(i am new to `recyclerView` and Android please help!! TIA)

Comment: Can you post the current code of the adapter and the fragment

Comment: You need to post more code,  I don't even know why you have a static context here in the first place because you should not have a static context....